# Pre tag rendering differently in IE10 compared to previous IE versions

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, pre

The following Html page is rendered differently on IE10 vs. earlier version of IE:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<pre style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:20; width:80;">
<label>My Label</label>
</pre>
<input style="position:absolute; top:0; left:100; height:20; width:80;" type="text" value="My Field"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On IE10 the label appears about 20 pixels lower than the input field in previous versions of IE the label and the field were aligned horizontally.

Note that:
1. clicking the compatibility mode button on IE10 fixes this problem.
2. Replacing the `<pre>` tag with `<span>` tag also fixes the problem but I need to maintain the `<pre>` tag.

I'm looking for a way to tell IE10 to render the `<pre>` tag the same way as previous versions without reverting to compatibility mode techniques.

IE10:

[image]

IE8:

[image]

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox, `<pre>` tag comes with a default `margin:1em 0px` style, so I guess IE10 is just "following the standard".

Comment: This example seems a little fabricated – why would one put a label in a pre element? If you want monospaced font and/or no automatic line breaking – then use CSS.

Comment: The example is taken from a real product. Wrapping the label with a <pre> element was necessary for supporting old versions of IE. The real product code that generates this page is over 10 years old.

Comment: Passerby, your suggestion looks promising. Adding margin:0px; to the Pre style seems to fix the problem. Need to test more.

Comment: Not to distract from the actual question, but why on earth are you using `<pre>` tags here anyway??? Couldn't you acheive the same effect by just sticking all that styling onto the `<label>` along with `font-face:courier`? `<pre>` tags have their legitimate uses, but this really doesn't look like one of them.

Comment: As I said this is legacy code I inherited, auto generated by server side component. Changing the tag structure is difficult since it breaks other code which relies on the existing DOM structure.

Comment: If this is legacy code which is difficult to update to work with modern browsers, why don't you just let Compatibility View do its thing, since that's what it's there for?

Comment: @BoltClock Other browsers don't have a compatibility mode, so that would be an IE-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

The document is rendered in quirks mode. Now different browsers have different quirks; apparently IE10 has different quirks than earlier versions of IE, hence the difference.

Solution: slap a DOCTYPE on top, so that it renders in standards mode. And correct the errors in the CSS (that is, add `px` to each of the lengths).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form>
   <pre style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:20px; width:80px; margin:0;">
    <label>My Label</label>
   </pre>
   <input style="position:absolute; top:0; left:100px; height:20px; width:80px;"
          type="text" value="My Field"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then it will display the same across browsers.